# Generating a word file from a form using php.

Tags: javascript, php, html, ms-word

I need to generate a word file every time someone completes a html form. Can someone help me with any piece of code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create and download a text file using php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11056033/create-and-download-a-text-file-using-php)

Comment: I find it extremely difficult to believe you found nothing in a web search about doing this

Comment: Something [like this](https://www.google.com/#q=Generating+a+word+file+from+a+form+using+php.) perhaps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use HTTP headers

```
<?php
  header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-word");
  header("Content-Disposition: attachment;Filename=document_name.doc");    
  echo "<html>";
  echo "<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=Windows-1252\">";
  echo "<body>";
  echo "<b>Demo Text</b>";
  echo "</body>";
  echo "</html>";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are tons of libraries for PHP to create Word files.

All you then have to do is adding this to your PHP file:

```
<?php
    header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");   
?>
```

This tells the browser that the resource should be downloaded. After that, you just have to output the contents of your generated Word-file.